# Aptana Studio 3's Updater doesn't work (win 7)

Tags: aptana3

My Aptana Studio 3 Updater shows just this message (it gets the update (from 3.2.2 to 3.3.1 ...) correctly, as far as I can see):

> Insufficient access privileges to apply this update.

My system is a standard Windows 7 System - do I have to change any access privileges of my folders to get a successfully finished update?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried running Aptana as an administrator? http://www.online-tech-tips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/RunasAdministratorWindows7_thumb.png

Comment: Yes, now I did. But by doing this, Aptana lost it's workspace and all projects. Are there any suggestions, how to fix this? It seems like Aptana lost all preferences, too.

Comment: All right, my projects are back (Import Wizard -> General -> Existing Project into Workspace). Thank you!